# Trouble with JScrollPane in JTextArea in JPanel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a  `JTextArea` in a `JPanel` that I would like to use a `JScrollPane` with.  I am using `GridBagLayout`.  When I run it it seems the frame makes room for the `JScrollPane` but it does  not show up, any help would be appreciated.  I have been trying to study the docs.oracle page and here [Add JScrollPane to a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221017/add-jscrollpane-to-a-jpanel) but for some reason it refuses to show up.

```
final JTextArea test= new JTextArea(5,30);
test.setLineWrap(true);
test.setWrapStyleWord(true);
test.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane spane = new JScrollPane(test);
spane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);        

JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

frame.setSize(800, 250);
frame.setTitle("test1");
frame.setLocation(300, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.getContentPane().add(spane);

GridBagConstraints k = new GridBagConstraints();
k.gridx = 4;
k.gridy = 5;
a.setConstraints(spane,k);
container.add(spane);
```

Comment: If I add    spane.setViewportView(panel); a panel shows up but the JTextArea that the panel should be used for just tried to get bigger to fill the text instead of staying the same size and letting me use the scrollpane

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable container is JPanel? I think you forget to call the add() method. But below is my suggestion code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyScrollPane extends JPanel
{

    public MyScrollPane()
    {   
        GridBagConstraints k = new GridBagConstraints();
        k.gridx = 4;
        k.gridy = 5;



        final JTextArea test= new JTextArea(5, 30);
        test.setLineWrap(true);
        test.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        test.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane spane = new JScrollPane(test);
        spane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl.setConstraints(spane,k);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(gbl);     
        panel.add(spane);
        add(panel);

    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 250);
        frame.setTitle("test1");
        frame.setLocation(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyScrollPane());



        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem ended up being that in GridBagLayout I had added the TextArea with its own constraints so I had constraints for the JScrollPanel and constraints for the JTextArea.  Once I removed all formatting from the JTextArea and then replace JTextArea with JScrollPane only in the GridBagLayout it worked like a charm.  Your post helped a lot when I saw that you had only added the gbl.SetConstraints for spane and not for test.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the last five lines of your code and changed it a little. I works just fine.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {



private JTextArea test = new JTextArea(5, 30);
private JScrollPane spane;

public MainFrame() {

    this.setSize(800, 250);
    this.setTitle("test1");
    this.setLocation(300, 300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);

    test.setLineWrap(true);
    test.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    test.setEditable(false);
    spane = new JScrollPane(test);
    spane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    this.getContentPane().add(spane);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need GridBagConstraints though since I am using GridBagLayout.

Comment: You are not using the GridBagLayout. You added the scrollpane to the content pane of the frame. By default the content pane uses a BorderLayout. If you want to use a GridBagLayout then you should read [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for working examples and explanations on how to use the constraints.